# Scheduling notification on a specific time stored in the database

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project there i need to implement notifications one day before the expiry of the documents , hour before the pickup etc. And the dates for the expiry and pickup are stored in the database I have to fetch it and send a notification to the user.

I need to implement something that could fetch the data when the expiry is near can i use firebase cloud messaging for the same? or any other ways to do it more efficiently.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where data is stored in local database or remote database?

Comment: Remote database

Comment: See in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

If data stored in remote database then there is two possible way.
First, all logic have to implement in remote side and server will send payload for notification, which you have to triggered through FCM.
And secondly, you can call api and implement notification on app side.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom Firebase Cloud function that would run on a certain schedule (1h or 5 mins, based on your usecase) and would check if any documents expire within a given timeframe. If you find such documents, issue a FCM to notify the owners of the document.

It is not a good idea to implement this behavior in the app itself because nobody can guarantee that the application will be live at the time when the check should be performed. This is primarily due to android battery optimizations introduced in the latest OS versions.

For more info and examples, look at the following documentation:

Cloud Functions - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Scheduled functions - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions